# Android device recognised by "adb devices" but not via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have just performed a new Linux install (LinuxLite 2.2) for Android (inc NDK) development on Eclipse and have the unexpected issue that when I run "adb devices", "adb shell" etc from the command line they perform as expected but when I start the debugger from Eclipse there is no device shown in the Android Device Chooser.

I have updated the Android SDK and am using NDK version 10d which is the latest.

I have tried resetting ADB from the Eclipse DDMS/Devices tab dropdown, running "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server" as well as restarting the computer but nothing fixes the problem.

I am not able to move to Android Studio at this time.

Any ideas greatly appreciated,

Comment: Can you see the device in DDMS Perspective from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the device in the DDMS just double click

if not check if you use the same location for the adb in eclipse as in command line

write in the shell

> which adb

Comment: I can see the device in the DDMS Devices window but double-clicking it has no effect (doesn't work on a working system either, btw).  There is only one copy of adb in my system, "which adb" gives "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb"  This directory os owned and grouped by my user name, not root.